# Jquery Ajax wont bind Href

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am calling ajax via jquery in an effort to load an href. The html seems to load correctly. However, the html that is loaded (href) does not actually work. Specifically, I can't figure out why once the link loads via ajax, it doesn't actually do anything when I click it. No errors in firebug, just dead link. Is my .on() method incorrect?

**home.html**

```
<html>
<head></head>
<body>
<div id="connections">Placeholder Text</div>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.1/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
var uri='home-ajax.html'; //first find out if this is created yet   
var myVar=setInterval(function(){example_ajax_request()},8000); //to do that check for it ev. 8 sec.
function example_ajax_request() {
    $.ajax({
        type: 'GET',
        url: 'home-ajax.html', //checking
        dataType: 'html', //html is content inside home-ajax.html
            success: function() {               
                $('#connections').load('home-ajax.html'); //if home-ajax exists replace connections div with its content
                clearInterval(myVar); //stop the 8 sec. timer
            },
            error: function (xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError) {
                alert(xhr.status);
                alert(thrownError);
            }
    });

}

$('myLink').on('click', function(e) { //using .on to actively bind new href link from ajax()
    document.location.href="http://www.cnn.com";//when href with id='myLink' is clicked, go to www.cnn.com
});
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

**home-ajax.html**

```
<p><a href="#" id="myLink">CNN</a></p>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That element did not exist on page load, so you can't bind a click function directly to it. You have to delegate the click to a static element.

```
$(document).on('click', '#myLink', function(e){
    e.preventDefault(); // stop default action
    document.location.href="http://www.cnn.com"; //do work
});
```

Comment: Thank you! Quick follow up. What would change in your answer if I added another link like: <p><a href="#" id="myLink2">fox.com</a></p>

Comment: @Crhis it would be `#myLink2`, but...i all links went to the same place, we could just capture the click on any element that starts with `myLink`, `$(document).on('click', '[id^=myLink]', function(){`